# How to add door trim where there isn't enough room?

Tags: doors, trim

I'm adding molding to my living room, but have one entryway where there isn't enough room on the side to add the full width of the pilaster.

What are my options?  I do plan on having a 5" base molding, a 2" chair rail, and a 3" crown, if that affects what might look good.

[image]
[image]

Comment: How wide is that opening? Could you afford to lose a few inches to build up that 1" side wall so that it's wide enough for the trim?

Comment: I'm not thrilled at losing a few inches in the opening, but I suspect that's the best/correct answer and I may just have to bite the bullet...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are only 2 options I can think of.

1. Rip the trim down so it is narrow for the place where it won't fit.
2. Build out the opening so the trim will fit.

Which is better is entirely a personal preference.

Option 1 is easier. I've had to do this with door trim and haven't been unhappy.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a drawing that shows how I would do it.[image]